# API PHP Script Question

Tags: php, api

I'm writing a PHP script that will handle requests from outside sources.
Does it matter that thousands of requests will be handled by one PHP script? Is this efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to know is, an instance of the script is created on each request.

It doesn't matter if you have a single script called 1000 times at once or 1000 scripts called at the same time.

Your bottle neck might be elsewhere like database or file io. So don't worry, you can do as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see reason why this would be problem. If you do not use > 5 queries per API request, it's easy to proccess it all (depends on many factors)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference if you have two identical scripts on the same server that handle half of the requests each, if that's what you're asking.